# Using a form builder with custom CSS and need help changing the button alignment

Tags: css, button

I am using a form builder to build a multistep form and insert my own custom css to change the layout of the form. Cannot seem to grab onto the "next" and "previous" buttons.

I am using "Easy Forms" to build custom multi-step forms with logical conditions. If you are not familiar with Easy Forms, it is basically drag and drop with the ability to insert html snippets and set css container classes on each question you set in the form. Then, you have access to the css code to create your own "theme" for the form.

I have access to the "submit" button during the drag and drop process so I have been able to set a css class for that and in my css I have centered it using off-sets and "col-...". However, I cannot seem to grab a hold of the "next" and "previous" buttons as this is a multi-step form with multiple page breaks. Easy Forms does not give me a way to access or edit the next and previous buttons (as far as I have been able to discern) so I cannot assign a css class to them.

I have published the form and looked at the html code of what Easy Forms assigns to the next and previous buttons.

This is what it looks like in the html code:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary next">Next</button>
```

I do not have access to the html code to just throw a centered div in there so I have to somehow hook onto these buttons through css.

Here are some of my attempts

```
.btn {
    box-sizing: border-box !important;
    border: 0 !important;
    border-bottom: 3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) !important;
    font-family: "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    padding: 16px 32px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.btn-primary {
    background-color: rgb(10,31,46);
    box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3),inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.07),0 1px 1px rgba(10,13,25,0.5);
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
}

.btn-primary:hover, .btn-primary:active, .btn-primary:focus {
    background-color: #163348; !important;
    background-color: #163348 !important;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3),inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.07),0 1px 1px rgba(10,13,25,0.5) !important;
    outline: 2 !important;
}

.previous {
    text-align:center; 
    margin: auto;
}

.next {
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Centered Next & Previous Buttons

Answer (score 0):

Added three different arrangements of buttons with Bootstrap Flex classes.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Using a form builder with custom CSS and need help changing the button alignment</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
<style>
.btns button {
 margin: 0 20px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
      <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small> </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-check">
      <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Check me out</label>
    </div>
    <div class="btns d-flex justify-content-center">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary previous">Prev</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary next">Next</button>
    </div>
    <div class="btns d-flex justify-content-between">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary previous">Prev</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary next">Next</button>
    </div>
    <div class="btns d-flex justify-content-around">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary previous">Prev</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary next">Next</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Awesome answer! and while I think it will work I do not have access to the html code regarding these buttons to create those classes for them. At least not easily

Comment: If the buttons are covered with a div or any element. Can use like example have .btns covered.

 .btns{display:flex; justify-content:space-between;}